# Should we change the title of the question about the black triangle in the Cabin?

Tags: discussion, search

I am speaking about this question: [What does this placard on board an A320 denote?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39634/what-does-this-placard-on-board-an-a320-denote)

As the Stackexchange network aims for a high rate of users coming from search engines and this question is about something many passengers of airplanes may ask themselves, I feel like no one would search for a "placard". They would instead search for something containing the word "black triangle" in it.

So, in terms of search engine optimization, I would change the title of the question into something like:

> What does that black triangle in the cabin of passenger aircraft mean?

Or similar.

What would you say? Have you got a better fitting title?

Comment: If you really want to, you could change "placard" to "black triangle placard" in the title and/or body. That makes the information more specific without removing the OP's original, correct terminology. But in general, trying to guess what words other people will use doesn't seem like a good idea. After all, the OP used the word that you said "no one" would use :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On SE, you are always welcome to propose changes that improve a post. At >=2000 rep, your changes are applied immediately.

If your changes are inappropriate, the OP or another community member may rollback your edit. When you're unsure, you can leave a comment to explain your intentions of the change.

In this particular example, I agree that your new title is better than the original one. But I will leave it to you to change so as not to "steal your idea".